# how to capture video without showing the camera window or program

Tags: android

i want to capture in android programming without showing the camera
only want to have two button, by clicking first button, it start capturing and by clicking the second, capturing will be stop and save the file somewhere in phone.
also saw this link [Video Recording and Image Capture on Android using Camera Intents](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Recording_and_Image_Capture_on_Android_using_Camera_Intents#Summary)

its first week that i started android programming, thanks for your helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to capture videos on Android.

The first way is to use an Intent (a message) to ask applications able to capture video to start and to capture the video for you.

The second way is to build your own video recorder.

The first option is not suitable for you, as you will not be able to control the display of the called application.

Concerning the second option, there is a great tutorial on the official website about how to develop a camera application. Here is the link [Camera App tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera). Basically you will want to look to the part called "Building a Camera App" and "Capturing video". As you will see through the tutorial they use a SurfaceView (which you put in your layout just as any other view) to display the camera content. You can just follow the tutorial and then set the visibility of the view to false. Or, if you're more confident, you can try to skip part using the surfaceview.

Hope i could help !